# MySQL Query get Data form GROUP BY and Multiple ORDER BY with Many Relation Table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a vehicle queue system. I will retrieve data from each of the 1 data by category with certain conditions it is priority.

Priority order:
1. loadtypes.priority_order = ASC (1,2,3,4,...), then
2. queues.date_plan = ASC (2020-04-17,2020-04-18,...), then
3. windows.priority_order = ASC (1,2,3,4,...), then
4. queues.queue_number = asc (MAT-0001, MAT-0002, MAT-0003)

**Table LoadType**

[image]

**Table Window**

[image]

**Table Queues**

[image]

Order Query by priority:

```
SELECT loadtypes.loadtype_code, queues.date_plan, windows.window_name, queues.queue_number FROM queues,loadtypes,windows WHERE queues.loadtype_id=loadtypes.loadtype_id AND queues.window_id=windows.window_id ORDER BY loadtypes.priority_order ASC, queues.date_plan ASC, windows.priority_order ASC, queues.queue_number ASC
```

[image]

Now, i will get 1 data form group loadtype by first row from order priority above.

[image]

This is my trouble query:

```
SELECT loadtypes.loadtype_code, queues.date_plan, windows.window_name, queues.queue_number FROM queues,loadtypes,windows WHERE queues.loadtype_id=loadtypes.loadtype_id AND queues.window_id=windows.window_id ORDER BY loadtypes.priority_order ASC, queues.date_plan ASC, windows.priority_order ASC, queues.queue_number ASC GROUP BY queues.loadtype_id
```

Thanks.

Comment: are you using `MySQL 8.0` then you can do by using window functions?

Comment: i dont know @zealous, but i using codeigniter 3 and Xampp PHP 7

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MySQL 8.0`, then following solution will work. Also you should use `JOIN` instead of joining tables on `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT 
    lt.loadtype_code, 
    q.date_plan, 
    w.window_name, 
    q.queue_number
FROM    
(
    SELECT 
        lt.loadtype_code, 
        q.date_plan, 
        w.window_name, 
        q.queue_number,
        row_number() over (partition by lt.loadtype_code order by window_name) as rnk

    FROM queues q

    JOIN loadtypes lt
    ON q.loadtype_id = lt.loadtype_id

    JOIN windows w
    q.window_id = w.window_id

) final
where rnk = 1
```